# fullCalendar on click of date number - get Date data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, onclick, fullcalendar

I'm having an issue with the FullCalendar jQuery Library, found HERE:

I'm attempting change up the normal functionality of things. When clicking the date number in month view instead of it switching to DAY view, I want it to go to another page and pass the date attribute int he data-goto attribute that is listed.

Each day, after the calendar is render has this markup:

```
<td class="fc-day-top fc-xxx fc-yyyy" data-date="YYYY-MM-DD">
     <a class="fc-day-number" data-goto='{"date": "YYYY-MM-DD", "type":"day"}'>DD</a>
<td>
```

So after initializing the calendar, I have an on click event:

```
$('.fc-day-number').each(function(){
     var $this =  $(this);
     $this.on('click', function(){
          console.log($(this).data('goto', 'date'));
     });
});
```

BUT, when I click on the number of the date, it gives me a **`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined`**

All I want to do, just to make sure it's collecting the proper data is just get the date value from the goto data-attribute. Once I have that then loading a new page is easy.

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: that was a typo. the markup is automatically generated by FullCalendar. I can corrected it in my original question. My question has nothing to do with the markup that is generated anyways.

Comment: again, typo. it has been fixed in the question

Answer (score 0):

So I found a work around that, albeit doesn't serve 100% of the criteria, but still works all the same.

For the number in each cell, I applied a pointer-events: none, so that it would be non-clickable, and in the initialization code for FullCalendar, I took advantage of the dayClick method and used THAT to pass through the date, add that to a URL query and the simple javascript to redirect the page.

Here's the code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     dayClick: function(date){
          var dateFormat = date.format()
          console.log("Clicked on: "+dateFormat); //returns the date
          window.location.href = "newPage.jsp?datepicker="+dateFormat;
     }
});

$('a.fc-day-number').each(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.css('pointer-events','none');
});
```